# How do I sort (x,y) data points for a non-function with one point following the other, eg. for plotting in Excel

Tags: graphing-functions, sorting

I have a set of (x,y) data points which describe an envelope or wiggly line. That is for certain x values, there are more than one y values, and for certain y values there are more than one x value.

A circle is an example of this, although my data describes an open version of a squashed version of a circle.

I would like to sort this data such that each data point follows the one before, much like following a point around the circumference of the circle from one point around the circle back to itself, although in my case it does not have to come back to the start.  I just need to sort all the data points such that I follow the curve from the start to end.

Obviously sorting by x value or y value does not work.  Are there any algorithms to sort the data points the way I require?

Comment: No that won't work, my data has both convex and concave regions in the same curve, so $\theta$ is non-monotonic.

Comment: @user121049, I thought about that, but I see in general a possible inconvenince. Let us imagine a self-intersecting curve, like a horizontal 8 cebtered on the origin. By following $\theta$ we start at the rightmost point and  follow the curve getting to the centre for $\theta =\frac{ \pi}{2}$. After that point, it will continue on a brnach below the $x-$axis, while possibly the OP might want it to smoothly follow the curve orientaion

Comment: Luckily the curve does not self-intersect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that these points are so numerous that for any given point, the nearest distinct points are on the same section of your expected curve than a different section, you may use a greedy algorithm used in the travelling salesman problem.

Select any point as the first in a list.  Now for the latest point on the list, calculate the Euclidean distance to all other points that are not currently on the list; you can make his more efficient by limiting the comparisons based on a maximum difference in either or both coordinates. Select the point thus described with the least such distance and add it to the list. Repeat this until all points are on the list.

Note that if a point lies too far from the expected curve, it may be "skipped" by this algorithm and then placed at the end of the list. Orientation of the list is also not determined, except by the point chosen first, since this algorithm will (almost) always move in a single direction.

Comment: The data points are very numerous and dense, so this looks like a good solution.  However I will need to determine how to define the start point.  If I start in the middle somewhere, it will just march to the end in one direction and I won't get the other bit of the curve.

Comment: Your assumption might be not trivial to check in genral (not saying it will not work on this specific case, just found the problem very interesting and would like to see a general solution). The curve might be wiggly enough, containing "small-scale" undulations. Locally the curve might be flat, with an, say, almost circular loop (like an $\Omega$ shape): coming from the left, maybe the right horizontal segment of the $\Omega$ base is closer than any point on the left-curve, and we might completely skip the curved part of the $\Omega$

Comment: I create my data points in 2 passes, firstly along the x-axis, and then along the y-axis.  So my data points are equi-spaced on the x-axis and equi-spaced on the y axis.  Not sure if that helps.

Comment: The assumption is a necessary aspect of the algorithm; I have proven that exists a type of case (and there are ostensibly others, especially in >2 dimensions) where the algorithm can be forced to produce the least optimal result, precisely because of that issue. But if valid, the assumption makes it a very powerful algorithm, as the other issues (i.e. calculation times) are much easier to deal with. It is only a greedy algorithm, and others are known to be better anyway. @Anaedonist

Comment: You could simply let it run as described; if it finds no new points within a distance $d$ of the last point, it will terminate, and presumably this could only happen at a true end point. Now you repeat the process using only points not in the first list, and so on. Then stitching the lists together (run the algorithm on the lists themselves, defining them as both of their endpoints simultaneously, and allowing lists to reverse order when required?) is the last step. @dacfer

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you!